# Как получить значение в родительскую функцию из функции объекта Promise '.then"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-controller

Есть 2 инпута со значениями `calendarStart` и  calendarEnd,которые мне надо изменить.

вот мой .js :

```
$scope.calendarStart = new Date();
$scope.calendarEnd = new Date();
$scope.calendarEnd.setDate($scope.calendarEnd.getDate() + 7);

var firstEndDate = new Date();
var firstStartDate = new Date();
var startData = "calendarStart";
var endData = "calendarEnd";

$scope.changeCalendarStart = function () {           
    dataService.settings_get(startData).then(function(response) {
        firstStartDate = response;
        if (firstStartDate != null) {
            $scope.calendarStart = firstStartDate;
        }
        return firstStartDate;
     });
     return firstStartDate;
};
```

Как мне достать `response` из `dataService`,чтобы значение сохранилось?

Comment: в приведенном коде уже сохраняется в глобальную переменную _firstStartDate_, а так же в _$scope.calendarStart_ - в чем именно проблема?

Comment: О! Опять асинхронность :)